# AWS S3 Cache-Control 0 TTL 0 Not Updating

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I set my index.html and bundle.js to have cache-control of 0. But the S3 bucket still does not serve my updated files. I also tried setting TTL in my CloudFront to 0.

Comment: This happens whenever you replace a existing file you need to invalidate the cloud front distribution.

Comment: I tried to invalidate the CloudFront distribution with `/*` still doesn't work.